# How to implement regex on a powershell find and replace to quickly change file names in windows 10?

Tags: command-line, powershell, regex, rename, batch-rename

Hi I have a set of files in a folder (windows 10) that are named something like this:

`asfdjlaksjfdi09908jfakl.part1.rar`

`aabdjkhihsdjkf.part2.rar`

`sdjklufia9798uiownlnsadkfasdFASDFrwe34342.part3.rar`

`... etc`

The bit before the first `.` is of variable length and is basically just gibberish.

I want to quickly be able to change the everything before the first `.` to the same name it doesn't matter what that is so for example I want the above file names to be:

`file.part1.rar`

`file.part2.rar`

`file.part3.rar`

`... etc`

I have seen some powershell scripts to find and replace but I don't know how to do find and replace only up until the first `.`.

Is this even possible. From some googling I think this can be done with something called regular expressions but I don't have a clue.

**What I have tried so far:**

So I got the following which works for find and replace but I don't know how to change the find to work for everything up to the first `.` with regex.

`ls *.rar | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "asfdjlaksjfdi09908jfakl","file"}`

Basically I just need to change the `asfdjlaksjfdi09908jfakl` to be a regex that just replaces everything up until the first `.`

Can anyone help me with a quick script?

Thanks!!!

Comment: https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2013150/2165530) provides the regular expression you are looking for.

Now, applied to your specific case:

```
Get-ChildItem `
    -Filter "*.part*.rar" `
    -File `
    | Rename-Item `
        -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^[^\.]*','file' }
```